# How do I run a command as the system administrator (root)

Tags: linux, pip, virtualenv, sudo

I'd like to install virtualenv via pip in one line. I need root priviledges to do this. Something like this:

```
sudo su -c "pip install virtualenv"
```

or

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Above commands do not work, because of broken connection...

```
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0fcc648510>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/virtualenv/
```

In two lines it works:

```
sudo su -
pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: You don't need to be root to install virtualenv. You can pass `--user` to pip instead to install to your home directory

Comment: Do you require a proxy to access the internet in this environment? In some environments, all connections that doesn't go through the forward proxy are blocked. You may need to set http_proxy/https_proxy environment variable, so it's passed to the child process through sudo. Normally, sudo filters environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that only a root user can access internet directly or via proxy. When su to root you are loading the root environment variables ( source bashrc ) which will make the difference here.